# Show data on a specified template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using one plugin known as **Wp store Locator** which is **not based on custom post type**.So that plugin gives one list of store as output and it has in built template for it.I have modified that plugin in a such way that on click of **More Details** it should take me to detail page of that particular clicked store.

I have built link like this `localhost/wordpress/?wpsl-id=3`.

So my question is that how can I show only on particular store? I have built one template in that plugin but I don't have any idea how can I use that.

Any help from Wp Store Locator user would be highly appericiated.